# Repeating image count for both directories

Tags: php

I'm using the glob function in PHP to browse directories and trying to also match up only the image files. This is working but when I try to count the images in each directory, it repeats the count of the first directory for the others. For example, directory 1 has 6 images and directory 2 has 4 images but when I try to display the count for each directory, it shows 6 images for directory 2 and so forth.

Here is the code I have in place:

```
public function viewphotoalbumsAction()
{
    $identity = $this->identity();
    $dirname = array();
    $files = array();

    foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $identity . '/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $dirname[] = basename($dir);

        foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
            $files[] = $images;
        }
    }
    //var_dump($files); exit;

    $data = array(
        'albums' => array_values($dirname),
        'files'  => $files,
    );

    return new ViewModel(array('album' => $data['albums'], 'files' => $data['files']));
}
```

The results of var_dump()

```
 array(9) { [0]=> string(96) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/bone mom's album_2017-07-03/massive snow.jpg"
[1]=> string(91) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/bone mom's album_2017-07-03/mom-jon.jpg" 
[2]=> string(90) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/bone mom's album_2017-07-03/sunset.jpg" 
[3]=> string(85) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/cref.jpg" 
[4]=> string(88) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/diploma.jpg" 
[5]=> string(86) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/eeyor.jpg" 
[6]=> string(93) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/frother-jaws.jpg" 
[7]=> string(88) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/frother.jpg" 
[8]=> string(93) "C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/profile/fooboy/albums/random photos_2017-07-02/goat_singing.jpg" }
```

It is getting all the images from each directory as expected but what I really need to do is separate the images so I can have a accurate count for each directory and not just have it show the whole count (9)

The view code:

```
<div class="w3-col m7">
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="w3-col m12">
            <div class="w3-card-2 w3-round w3-white">
                <div class="w3-container w3-padding" id="view-photo-albums">
                    <p class="w3-center">Current Albums</p>
                    <br>
                    <?php
foreach ($this->album as $albums):
    ?>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $albums; ?> - Number of images: <?php echo $this->files; ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

I cannot use `array_values` for `$data['files']` as I did for `$data['albums']` as it is giving a warning of array to string conversion.

Comment: Check out my answer, tested and it works. It will also solve the problem you experience explained in your update about `$data['files']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem in this fragment of code:

```
foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
     $files[] = $images;
}
```

The variable `$dir` was used to iterate the array returned by the first invocation of `glob()`:

```
foreach (glob(...) as $dir) {
    ...
}
```

Its value after the first `foreach` loop ends is the last value that was assigned to it into the `foreach` loop.

In the end, `$data['albums']` contains all the directory names and `$data['files']` contains the names of the files inside the last directory listed in `$data['albums']`.

> I cannot use array_values for $data['files'] as I did for $data['albums'] as it is giving a warning of array to string conversion.

[`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) doesn't produce anything new for the `$dirname` and `$files`. If they are created (!) these two variables contain values indexed by sequential numbers starting with `0`; this is exactly what `array_values()` returns.

The intention of the code you posted is not very clear for me. I assume you want to display the list of albums and how many images contain each album.

This is how I would do it:

```
public function viewphotoalbumsAction()
{
    $identity = $this->identity();

    // Always initialize the arrays before putting values into them.
    // Without this, if the first glob() returns an empty array, the outer
    // foreach loop never runs and both $dirname and $files end up being undefined
    // and this produces trouble in the code that uses these variables later.
    $dirname = array();
    // This will be a two dimensional array. It is indexed by directory
    // names and contains the lists of files for each directory.
    $files   = array();

    // The outer loop enumerates the albums
    foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $identity . '/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        // The directory name is the album name
        $albumName = basename($dir);

        // Put the album name in $dirname[]
        // This is not really needed as we also have the album name
        // as key in $files but can be useful if you want to keep more
        // information about each album
        $dirname[] = $albumName;

        // Initialize the list of images of this album
        $files[$albumName] = array();

        // The inner loop enumerates the images of this directory
        foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
            $files[] = $images;
        }
    }

    // Prepare the data for display
    $data = array(
        'albums' => $dirname,
        'files'  => $files,
    );

    return new ViewModel($data);
}
```

The view (ignored the HTML wrapper, it is ok as it is):

```
<?php foreach ($this->files as $albumName => $listFiles): ?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $albumName; ?> - Number of images: <?php echo count($listFiles); ?>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As a remark, the inner `foreach` loop is not even needed because all it does is to copy one by one the values from the array returned by `glob()` into a new array.

It is faster and easier to read and understand to just store the value returned by `glob()` into `$files[$albumName]`. Since the values stored in `$dirname` are never used, this variable can be omitted completely and the function becomes shorter (comments omitted):

```
public function viewphotoalbumsAction()
{
    $identity = $this->identity();
    $files    = array();

    foreach (glob(getcwd().'/public/images/profile/'.$identity.'/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $albumName = basename($dir);
        $files[$albumName] = glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
    }

    return new ViewModel(array('files' => $files));
}
```

Comment: that does work but for some reason it is only saying there is three images in the first directory when there is 4.

Comment: There are also three images in the first directory in the output of `print_r()` you posted in the question. I guess the `glob()` wildcard doesn't match the fourth one. What's its name?

Comment: does it matter if the extension is in caps? like .JPG, because that is the one that is missing from the count

Comment: yeah, i guess it does, I just changed it and it showed up correctly. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't know how `glob()` is implemented on Windows. In theory, on Windows `*.jpg` should match both files ending in `.jpg` and `.JPG` but I won't rely on that. Especially if you develop the code on Windows but you intend to deploy it on a Linux server (where `*.jpg` definitely won't match `.JPG`). You better make the file extension lowercase when the file is uploaded and avoid uncertain results with `glob()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use foreach for files array also :

```
//its a demo 
foreach(array_combine($a,$b) as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key."<br/>".$value;
}//its a demo
```

Try this:

```
<div class="w3-col m7">
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col m12">
        <div class="w3-card-2 w3-round w3-white">
            <div class="w3-container w3-padding" id="view-photo-albums">
                <p class="w3-center">Current Albums</p>
                <br>
                    <?php

 foreach(array_combine($this->album,$this->files) as $albums=>$files) :
    ?>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $albums; ?> - Number of images: <?php echo files; ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error of Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in C:\xampp\htdocs\module\Members\view\members\profile\view-photo-albums.phtml on line 70

Comment: Don't you have same number of albums and file counts ? error occurs when you don't have equal numbersof key and values .

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to explicitly declare variable type array i.e.

```
public function viewphotoalbumsAction()
{
    $identity = $this->identity();
    $dirname = array();
    $files = array();
   // continue ...
}
```

let me know if works. thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing like variables declaration in PHP. Each variable comes into existence the first time it is used (for reading or writing, it doesn't matter). It is, indeed, the best practice to initialize the array variables before putting values into them to avoid unexpected results in some contexts. However, it doesn't help here.

Comment: No, it never triggers a Fatal Error for a missing variable. It trigger Notices if you want to access indices that doesn't exist in the array and Warnings in some other contexts (`foreach`, `array_merge()` etc). As I said, it is good to initialize `$dirname` and `$files` as you suggested, but it doesn't help here. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: I think this should work. as in case of foreach declaring say $files array outside the loop and use $files[] to add items to the array works well for me.

Comment: Well, if the first `glob()` returns an empty array, the `foreach` loop doesn't run and, in the original code, `$dirname` is not initialized and this generates warnings (and possibly errors) downstream. By initializing it with `array()` you make sure it is always an array and it doesn't make trouble. But this doesn't solve the OP's problem. The code still reports the wrong number of files because the problem is in the way the files are iterated.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to end the first foreach statement after the end of the second one not before it so each $dir has its own $images

```
 public function viewphotoalbumsAction()
    {
        $identity = $this->identity();

        foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $identity . '/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
            $dirname[] = basename($dir);



        foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
             $files[] = $images;
        }
    }

        $data = array(
            'albums' => array_values($dirname),
            'files'  => $files,
        );

        return new ViewModel(array('album' => $data['albums'], 'files' => count($data['files'])));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your public function de last `dir` will be the directory used in your second statement, which results in only the files counted in this folder.

change this:

```
foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/public/images/profile/' . $identity . '/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
        $dirname[] = basename($dir);
    }


    foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) {
         $files[] = $images;
    }
```

into

```
foreach (glob(getcwd() . '/images/albums/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) 
{
     $dirname[] = basename($dir);

         foreach (glob($dir . '/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $images) 
         {
          $files[] = $images;
         }
}
```

Comment: I did do that before and it does get all the images into a single array (9 elements) but it is displaying 9 images for each directory (as count() is being used)

Comment: that's because you count all the images, if you want to add them to distinct array, you can create an new array for each folder. I will update my answer with that option in a few seconds

Comment: I appreciate it :)

Comment: what is the result of the count you want in the example given?

Comment: there is 6 images in the first directory and then 4 in the second directory, I would like to have it display each images in the one directory and so forth

Comment: because right now its displaying the following:

bone mom's album_2017-07-03 - Number of images: 9

random photos_2017-07-02 - Number of images: 9

I would like to get it to display 6 for the 1st album then 4 for the 2nd directory and then if I add more albums, show the exact number of files in that directory and not the others